# jquery parallax sliding function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

I have tried implementing a jquery function which gives the parallax sliding effect, but its not working in my browser.

Here is the html code for the navigation bar once it clicks the pages slides down:

```
<!-- Menu -->
        <nav>
            <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right' id="navigate">
                <li class = "dropdown"><a href="#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"><span>About Us</span><b class = "caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                        <li data-slide = '1'><a href = "#">Philosophy</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Founding Members</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Committee</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Code of Ethics</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li data-slide='2'><a href="#">Digital Ecosystem</a></li>
                <li data-slide='3'><a href="#">Fellow & Members</a></li>
                <li data-slide='4'><a href="#">SIGs</a></li>
                <li data-slide='5'><a href="#">Local Chapters</a></li>
                <li data-slide="7"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li data-slide="8"><a href="#">Our Service</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Here is the JS code for the parallax sliding function:

```
 $(window).stellar();
//Cache some variables
var links = $('#navigate').find('li');
slide = $('.slide');
button = $('.button');
mywindow = $(window);
htmlbody = $('html,body');
//Setup waypoints plugin
slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {
    //cache the variable of the data-slide attribute associated with each slide
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    //If the user scrolls up change the navigation link that has the same data-slide attribute as the slide to active and
    //remove the active class from the previous navigation link
    if (direction === 'down') {
        $('#navigate li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
    }
    // else If the user scrolls down change the navigation link that has the same data-slide attribute as the slide to active and
    //remove the active class from the next navigation link
    else {
        $('#navigate li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
    }
});
//waypoints doesnt detect the first slide when user scrolls back up to the top so we add this little bit of code, that removes the class
//from navigation link slide 2 and adds it to navigation link slide 1.
mywindow.scroll(function () {
    if (mywindow.scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('#navigate li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
        $('#navigate li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
    }
});
//Create a function that will be passed a slide number and then will scroll to that slide using jquerys animate. The Jquery
//easing plugin is also used, so we passed in the easing method of 'easeInOutQuint' which is available throught the plugin.
function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
    htmlbody.animate({
        scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
    }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
}
//When the user clicks on the navigation links, get the data-slide attribute value of the link and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});
//When the user clicks on the button, get the get the data-slide attribute value of the button and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
button.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});
```